# Truncated videos in multi input multi output ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to copy videos from a CCTV DVR server (6 channels) using rtsp. How do I optimize my ffmpeg command?

Below is the configuration :

ffmpeg version : ffmpeg-4.1.4-win64-static 
CPU : Intel Core i7-8650U @1.9 GHz 2.11 GHz
RAM : 16 GB

When I try to download from 3 channels, the videos seem to download fine, but when I use >=4 channels simultaneously, the video from channel 1 truncates almost after about 5 secs, and the output files are much smaller from channel 2 to 4, channel 5 video output has no issues.

For e.g. here are the output file sizes according to channels.

```
Channel 1 : 1.7 MB (truncated)
Channel 2 : 27.5 MB (approx 5 secs video loss in the beginning)
Channel 3 : 28.5 MB (approx 3-4 secs loss)
channel 4 : 29.5 MB (approx 2 secs loss)
Channel 5 : 30 MB (no issues found)
```

Below is the command I am trying to use to download.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -thread_queue_size 1024 -i rtsp://<input url 1> -thread_queue_size 1024 -i rtsp://<input url 2> -thread_queue_size 1024 -i rtsp://<input url 3> -thread_queue_size 1024 -i rtsp://<input url 4> -thread_queue_size 1024 -i rtsp://<input url 5> -map 0 -vcodec copy -t 60 -y outputfile1.mp4 -map 1 -vcodec copy -t 60 -y outputfile2.mp4 -map 2 -vcodec copy -t 60 -y outputfile3.mp4 -map 3 -vcodec copy -t 60 -y outputfile4.mp4 -map 4 -vcodec copy -t 60 -y outputfile5.mp4
```

Below is the actual output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://<input url 1':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.080000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[udp @ 000001f27c6fffc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001f27c74f400] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 000001f27c721f40] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27c721f40] RTP: missed 15 packets
[h264 @ 000001f27d627ac0] error while decoding MB 71 49, bytestream -6
[h264 @ 000001f27d627ac0] concealing 2258 DC, 2258 AC, 2258 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 000001f27d627ac0] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://<input url 2':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[udp @ 000001f27c6ffc40] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001f27d2dc180] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 000001f27d2db700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27d2db700] RTP: missed 15 packets
[h264 @ 000001f27d2dbd00] concealing 7337 DC, 7337 AC, 7337 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 000001f27d2dbd00] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #2, rtsp, from '<input url 3':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.080000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[udp @ 000001f27c6ffd00] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001f27d302bc0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 000001f27cfe9200] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27cfe9200] RTP: missed 44 packets
[h264 @ 000001f27cfe6c40] error while decoding MB 41 24, bytestream -8
[h264 @ 000001f27cfe6c40] concealing 5288 DC, 5288 AC, 5288 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 000001f27cfe6c40] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #3, rtsp, from '<input url 4':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.080000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[udp @ 000001f27cfe0940] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001f27dd1bec0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[rtsp @ 000001f27daaf040] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27daaf040] RTP: missed 107 packets
[h264 @ 000001f27dc05040] concealing 1340 DC, 1340 AC, 1340 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 000001f27daaf040] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27daaf040] RTP: missed 28 packets
[h264 @ 000001f27dc05040] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
[h264 @ 000001f27dc05040] concealing 6961 DC, 6961 AC, 6961 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 000001f27daaf040] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27daaf040] RTP: missed 53 packets
[h264 @ 000001f27dc05040] error while decoding MB 16 40, bytestream -18
[h264 @ 000001f27dc05040] concealing 3393 DC, 3393 AC, 3393 MV errors in I frame
Input #4, rtsp, from 'rtsp://<input url 5':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.120000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #4:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'outputfile1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Output #1, mp4, to 'outputfile2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Output #2, mp4, to 'outputfile3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #2:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Output #3, mp4, to 'outputfile4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #3:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Output #4, mp4, to 'outputfile5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #4:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #1:0 (copy)
  Stream #2:0 -> #2:0 (copy)
  Stream #3:0 -> #3:0 (copy)
  Stream #4:0 -> #4:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 000001f27dd0d8c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 000001f27dd09040] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 000001f27dd09040] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 000001f27dc054c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 000001f27dc054c0] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 000001f27ddf86c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 000001f27ddf86c0] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 000001f27c743b00] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 000001f27c743b00] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 000001f27dd0d8c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27dd09040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 1:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27dc054c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 2:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27ddf86c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 3:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27c743b00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 4:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27dd09040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 1:0; previous: 1, current: 0; changing to 2. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27dc054c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 2:0; previous: 1, current: 0; changing to 2. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27ddf86c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 3:0; previous: 1, current: 0; changing to 2. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 000001f27c743b00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 4:0; previous: 1, current: 0; changing to 2. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[rtsp @ 000001f27d2db700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27d2db700] RTP: missed 1644 packets
[rtsp @ 000001f27c721f40] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27c721f40] RTP: missed 2461 packets
[rtsp @ 000001f27cfe9200] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000001f27cfe9200] RTP: missed 733 packets
frame=   46 fps=0.8 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 size=    1790kB time=00:00:59.99 bitrate= 244.4kbits/s speed=1.04x
video:119011kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Could somebody please help me optimize the ffmpeg command?

Comment: Have you tried with `-rtsp_transport tcp` for all inputs?

Comment: Yes I have tried adding -rtsp_transport tcp for all the inputs. What happens then is that the first two channels give truncated output, but the remaining ones have no loss of videos in them. Alternatively, I tried using udp for all the inputs as well, in that case the first two videos see losses, but kind of resume after about 10 secs, whereas in tcp the videos (the first two channels) stop altogether after 2 secs.

Comment: You need a ffmpeg binary with pthreads linked.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the socket buffer size for the RTP packets.

> buffer_size=size
>   Set the UDP maximum socket buffer size in bytes. This is used to set either the receive or send buffer size, depending on what the socket is used for. Default is 64KB. See also fifo_size.

Increase the buffering time of the packets.

-max_delay

From the logs it shows lot of packet loss is happening.

> RTP: missed 2461 packets

Also try each channel in separate process of ffmpeg.